# Error in y axis label in shiny app using cairo

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, cairo

so I wrote a shiny app for importing data and plotting it using ggplot2. If I use cairo for plotting

```
options(shiny.usecairo=T)
```

(should be active by default) plots are prettier but **y axis label "Oxygen consumption"** miss some parts.

Plot without cairo:

[image]

Plot with cairo:

[image]

Can someone point me towards a solution or have ideas what the mistake is?

Edit: here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
options(shiny.usecairo=T)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         sliderInput("size",
                     "size:",
                     min = 0.1,
                     max = 40,
                     value = 15)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   res<- reactive({input$resolution})
   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
     #refresh on
     print(input$resolution)
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      qplot(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', ylab = "Some long string to test for errors and see what is affected")+theme_classic(base_size=input$size)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So, for me it looks like some characters get cut on the right.

Edit: I narrowed this down to my windows machine, can't see it on shinyapps.io and local linux server anymore. Probably not so relevant then, since the error is only happening during development.

Comment: probably a better an idea to provide a reproducible example. By looking at the two images it's hard to tell the difference.

Comment: Hi, so the difference is in the **y axis label "Oxygen consumption"**, left part of the plot. I'll add an example later when I find the time.

Comment: FWIW, I run the minimal example on my linux device, no issue!